# Optimised ways to Deploy in Azure in multiple regions?

Tags: azure, deployment, storage, region

I am deploying virtual machines from VHDs in Azure in multiple regions. For every region I am creating new resource groups and storage accounts though VHD files are same which are used to create images. Is there any optimized way to use resources in Azure? Can I use blobs in one storage account for deployments in other regions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use many ways of automating deployment in azure. arm templates are, probably, the best one. for unmaanged disks I'm honestly not sure if you can create those with arm template from blob, but you can create a vm with unmanaged disk from existing blob:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {...},
        "osProfile": {...},
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                "offer": "WindowsServer",
                "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
                "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "name": "osdisk",
                "vhd": {
                    "uri": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))).primaryEndpoints.blob, 'vhds/osdisk.vhd')]"
                },
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage"
            },
            "dataDisks": [
                {
                    "name": "datadisk1",
                    "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                    "lun": 0,
                    "vhd": {
                        "uri": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))).primaryEndpoints.blob, 'vhds/datadisk1.vhd')]"
                    },
                    "createOption": "Empty"
                }
            ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {...},
        "diagnosticsProfile": {...}
    }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure you would need to create a managed image first if you want managed disks and that can be created from a blob uri, but they have to be in the same region (image and blob).

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-managed-disks-template-deployments